# String as Primary Key in Laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, migration, primary-key, laravel-artisan

I've had to change a table in my database so that the `primary key` isn't the standard `increments`.

Here's the migration,

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->text('code', 30)->primary();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->text('name');
        $table->text('comment');
    });
}
```

However, MySQL keeps returning with,

> Syntax error or access violation: 1170 BLOB/TEXT column 'code' used in
>   key specification without a key length (SQL: alter table `settings`
>   add primary key `settings_code_primary`(`code`)

I've tried leaving the normal `increments` `id` in there and modifying the table in a different migration but the same thing happens.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

`Laveral Version 5.4.23`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Change it to string.

```
$table->string('code', 30)->primary();
```